# Web.Contents stuck or times out while trying to download a file

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I cannot connect to the site on which there is a small xlsx file. The file is the Rig Count Summary on [this site](https://rigcount.bakerhughes.com/na-rig-count). Right-click > copy link to use in Power Query.

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(Web.Contents("https://rigcount.bakerhughes.com/static-files/3ba17f6e-62be-454c-bbd9-806996a7d991"), null, true)
 
in
    Source
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The web server gets the HTTP request and can behave differently based on the HTTP headers present in the request.  By trial-and-error you can copy request headers from a working request that you examine in browser debug mode or Fiddler and add them to Web.Contents.  The result of doing that here is something like:

```
let
    headers = [
    #"User-Agent"="Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 13_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/87.0.4280.77 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1 Edg/108.0.0.0"
    ,#"Accept-Encoding"="gzip, deflate"
    ],
    Source = Web.Contents("https://rigcount.bakerhughes.com/static-files/3ba17f6e-62be-454c-bbd9-806996a7d991",[Headers=headers]),
    Data = Excel.Workbook(Source),
    RigCountSummary_CurrentWeek_Sheet = Data{[Item="RigCountSummary_CurrentWeek",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data]
in
    RigCountSummary_CurrentWeek_Sheet
```

Without the `Accept-Encoding` and `User-Agent` headers the request was hanging on the web server.  This is probably a bug with that web application, instead of an anti-scraping measure, as you wouldn't intentially cause incoming requests to hang for a long time.

Comment: Brilliant. I swear I tried exactly that and copied all the headers from fiddler and it still didn't work for me. Good work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your site doesn't provide a direct link to the Excel file.

- When you click on the xlsx link, a java script starts the download of `Rig Count Summary_121622.xlsx`
- When you copy the xlsx link, you get `https://rigcount.bakerhughes.com/static-files/4ef2cc30-b5a4-4b91-856a-499467858baa`, which is not an Excel file.

Comment: Are you looking at the right link? I see no JS interfering with the download. This link opens an Excel file. https://rigcount.bakerhughes.com/static-files/3ba17f6e-62be-454c-bbd9-806996a7d991

Comment: Lucky you! But then it should be straight forward to import the data in Power BI?

Comment: @Peter I believe you copied the link for the PDF file. The xlsx file is the one above that.

Comment: @Peter - I think Web.Contents is getting HTTP 304 instead of the actual file on anything past the first connection, and does not know how to interpret it. Do you know of a way to force the call?

Comment: That's the problem. It doesn't work in PBI.

Comment: Interestingly, even passing a cache-control option with the Web.Contents does not work in this case, while it does work on that site through devtools. Something else is going on here.
https://datachant.com/2016/12/20/how-to-enforce-power-querypower-bi-to-import-uncached-data-from-the-web/

Comment: I can get a HTTP 200 code so I don't think it is anything to do with HTTP 304 you sometimes see. I think it could be a mime type problem or perhaps something to do with one of the headers like Content-Disposition.